# Finding form input fields using Mechanize where the field's label contains a string in a list of strings?

Tags: python, mechanize

Now I understand what the error means, but I'm curious why this doesn't work and if there is an alternative available which will complete the same task. I pass regex's when using Beautiful Soup and am disappointed to find that Mechanize does not support (?) the same functionality.
input_names is a dict.

```
TypeError: control label must be string-like

# first - as a default - set form inputs by their labels
for k in variables:
    for word in input_names[k]:
        for control in br.form.find_control(label=re.compile(word)):
            br.form.set_value(variables[k], name=control.name)
```

The goal is to match any form input whose label contains a phrase, rather than matches completely.

Also, any tips on efficiency or code prettying/elegance appreciated; I'm new to python.

**Workaround: (untested)**

```
for tag in soup.findAll("label"):
    for k in variables:
        # try to find label in <label>X</label>. It will not be in for="X" 
        # because if it was, we'd find it below anyway.
            for word in input_names[k]:
                if word in  tag.contents.lower():
                    try:
                        br.form.find_control(name=tag['for'], kind="text").value = variables[k]
                    except:
                        print "failed to set value of input found by label."
```

Comment: Post some sample HTML where a *"field's label contains a string in a list of strings"*?

Comment: basically, I know the field might be "name" or "firstname" or "fname" or "name_first", so I'm attempting to find any field whose name="X" contains the string name.

Comment: the primary question is why does br.form.find_control(label=re.compile(word)) not work and what can I do instead

Comment: You've gotta post us a HTML snippet and sample regexes, otherwise we can't follow you at all. Assuming *br.form.find_control()* doesn't take regexes, we'll need to solve it somehow, e.g. by manually finding and matching all controls. Alternatively, use BS with regex to make the match to literal text, then feed that back to mechanize.

Comment: I chose the later; see above. Thanks greatly for your idea.

Comment: Reposted as an answer, if you care to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `br.form.find_control()` doesn't take regexes, we'll need to solve it somehow, e.g. by manually finding and matching all controls. Alternatively, use `BS` with regex to make the match to literal text, then feed that back to `mechanize`.